# How to change position of tooltip triangle vertically

Tags: css

```css
/* TOOLTIP */
[tool-info] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer
}

[tool-info]:after,
[tool-info]:before {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none
}

[tool-info]:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 99%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -37px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, .9);
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(tool-info);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2
}

[tool-info]:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 76%;
  left: 185%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-top: 5px solid hsla(0, 0%, 20%, .9);
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0
}

[tool-info]:hover:after,
[tool-info]:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<a href="#" tool-info="tool-info">hover me</a>
```

On hover the tool tip appears but the triangle is incorrectly position how to move it upside down vertically so that the pointy side of the triangle points to the text while the other side is joined to the box to look as if its a part of the tooltip.

Comment: Switch the property value for border-top and border-bottom and maybe move the arrow element up using `top: -5px;`

Answer (score 1):

To have an arrow that points to the top (when using `border`s), you'll have to make all the four `border`s the same size and transparent and only the bottom on with a color.

Here's an example :

```css
/* TOOLTIP */
[tool-info] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer
}

[tool-info]:after,
[tool-info]:before {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none
}

[tool-info]:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 5px);
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -37px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, .9);
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(tool-info);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2
}

[tool-info]:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  /** the next two lines center the arrow horizontally with the "hover me" text **/
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent; /** all borders are 5px and transparent **/
  border-bottom-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, .9); /** override the color for the bottom border **/
  content: "";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0
}

[tool-info]:hover:after,
[tool-info]:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<a href="#" tool-info="tool-info">hover me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust border-width accordingly:

```css
/* TOOLTIP */
[tool-info] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer
}

[tool-info]:after,
[tool-info]:before {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none
}

[tool-info]:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 99%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -37px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, .9);
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(tool-info);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2
}

[tool-info]:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 76%;
  left: 185%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent hsla(0, 0%, 20%, .9) transparent;
  content: " ";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0
}

[tool-info]:hover:after,
[tool-info]:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<a href="#" tool-info="tool-info">hover me</a>
```